# How to set knockout.js visible binding to true on ajax succes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have an HTML div with the following knockout Binding (Visible):

```
<div class="row"  data-bind="visible: HotelMasterRow">
    <div class="col col-lg-4">
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit pull-right"></span> Hotel Master
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

On page load the visible binding is set to false. I am trying to toggle the visible binding upon Ajax success event. Following is my click binding to initiate Ajax request:

```
<button class="btn btn-success disabled" type="submit" data-bind="css: enablebtn, click: SearchHotel">Search</button>
```

JavaScript code to achieve the same is:

```
this.SearchHotel = function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:"../api/hotel_master_search.php",
                type:"get",
                data:{hotel: this.hotelName},
                cache: false,
                success:function(hotel_data){
                    var hotel_data = $.parseJSON(hotel_data);
                    this.HotelId = ko.observable(hotel_data[0].hotel_id);
                    this.SearchHotelName =  ko.observable(hotel_data[0].hotel_name);
                    this.HotelEN = ko.observable(hotel_data[0].hotelEN);
                    this.HotelCode = ko.observable(hotel_data[0].hotelcode);

                    this.HotelMasterRow(true);
                }
            });
        }
```

Even though the Ajax response did return the correct data, this.HotelMasterRow(true); doesn't seems to be working. The div is still not visible. Any Idea why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"this" does not refer to your model in the scope of the success callback. What you want to do is declare a variable refering to "this" in your model, and call this variable in your success callback. Something like that:

```
var Model = function() {
    var self = this;

    this.SearchHotel = function() {
        $.ajax({
            ...
          success: function(data) {
            ...
            self.HotelMasterRow(true);
            ...
          }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

So the other answer is absolutely correct, but I feel there is one key flaw that your code you are showing has in it outside of just the context of this vs self for the HotelMasterRow -

Your data set is going to be Knockout Observables, but I don't see how you plan to bind to them.  Since they are nested inside of the SearchHotel function, and presumably in your View Model and not the model, you are either going to have to have a hotel before you can search for it or you need to separate your model and view model logic and create an observable array to store your data in.  If there is only one object returned at a time then you can obviously use an Observable instead.

This does a number of things - it allows you to not have to bind specifically your visible binding to HotelMasterRow (no data will show unless there is data anyway) or if you want to continue doing that anyway it will allow you to separate your concerns and have good repeatable JavaScript -

Create a model in your JavaScript page (or wherever you want as long as it is accessible)

```
function HotelModel(id, name, en, code) {
    var self = this;        
    self.HotelId = ko.observable(id);
    self.SearchHotelName =  ko.observable(name);
    self.HotelEN = ko.observable(en);
    self.HotelCode = ko.observable(code);
}
```

And then on success in your Ajax call create an observable of type HotelModel and push it into the ObservableArray

```
self.Hotels = ko.observableArray();
self.SearchHotel = function(){
     $.ajax({
        url:"../api/hotel_master_search.php",
        type:"get",
        data:{hotel: this.hotelName},
        cache: false,
        success:function(hotel_data){
            var hdata = $.parseJSON(hdata);
            self.Hotels.push(new HotelModel(hdata[0].hotel_id, hdata[0].hotel_name, hdata[0].hotelEN, hdata[0].hotelcode));       
            self.HotelMasterRow(true);
        }
    });
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G5KAU/

Comment: Thanks. This definitely looks like a much neater approach to code.